# How to make two divs align right?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have two divs in my project (`dlgR` and `dlgDivR`).

The content of `dlgR` should be showed in the first row, and `dlgDivR`'s content should be showed in the second row. Here is what I want:

```
22:09:06 snow accept
     johntakeit
```

But actually, they are in the same row, like this:

```
johntakeit  22:09:06 snow accept
```

Here is CSS and HTML:

```css
.dlgR {
  float: right
}

.dlgDivR {
  float: right;
  text-align: right;
  margin-right: 5%;
  background: #E0FFFF;
  max-width: 70%
}
```

```html
<div class="dlgR"><label>22:09:06</label>&nbsp;<label>snow</label><label>&nbsp;accept</label></div>
<div class="dlgDivR"><span class="dlgSpan">johntakeit</span></div>
```

Maybe the reason is that these divs are in the tabs of jQuery UI. But I have no idea about it. Who can help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is to clear the float on your `.dlgDivR`

Give it `clear: right;` and it will work fine

```css
.dlgR {
  float: right;
}

.dlgDivR {
  float: right;
  clear: right;                  /*  added property  */
  text-align: right;
  margin-right: 5%;
  background: #E0FFFF;
  max-width: 70%
}
```

```html
<div class="dlgR"><label>22:09:06</label>&nbsp;<label>snow</label><label>&nbsp;accept</label></div>
<div class="dlgDivR"><span class="dlgSpan">johntakeit</span></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what are you trying to achieve? I have added a floated-right wrapper and changed styles a little:

```css
.wrapper {
  float:right
}
.dlgDivR {
  margin:auto;
  text-align:center;
  background:#E0FFFF;
  max-width:70%
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="dlgR"><label >22:09:06</label>&nbsp;<label >snow</label><label>&nbsp;accept</label></div>
  <div class="dlgDivR"><span class="dlgSpan" >johntakeit</span></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The layout is relatively simple with flexbox.

Make the parent of both divs a flex container. Then use flex properties to right-align the children.

No changes to the HTML are necessary.

```css
body {
  display: flex;           /* establish flex container */
  flex-direction: column;  /* stack child elements vertically */
  align-items: flex-end;   /* align child elements to the right */
}

dlgR {}

.dlgDivR {
  background: #E0FFFF;
}
```

```html
<div class="dlgR">
  <label>22:09:06</label>&nbsp;
  <label>snow</label>
  <label>&nbsp;accept</label>
</div>
<div class="dlgDivR"><span class="dlgSpan">johntakeit</span></div>
```